# How to enable filtering on all fields of a model in FastAPI

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

In Django with the restframework, you can do this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    another_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...
    (more attributes)
    ...
    yet_another_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    filterset_fields = '__all__' # <- this enables filtering on all fields
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
```

If I want to allow filtering, `filterset_fields = '__all__'` would allow me to do something like `api/item/?(attribute)=(value)` and allow me to filter on any attribute

I'm going through the tutorial (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#crud-utils) and it looks like there is a lot of manual filtering involved:

```
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import db

class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    another_attribute: str
    ...
    (more attributes)
    ...
    yet_another_attribute: str

# is it necessary to manually include all the fields I want to filter on as optional query parameters?
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_item(
    db: Session,
    id: Optional[int] = None,
    name: Optional[str] = None,
    another_attribute: Optional[str] = None,
    ...
    (more attributes)
    ...
    yet_another_attribute: Optional[str] = None
):
    # and then I'd need to check if the query parameter has been specified, and if so, filter it.
    queryset = db.session.query(Item)
    if id:
        queryset = queryset.filter(Item.id == id)
    if name:
        queryset = queryset.filter(Item.name == name)
    if another_attribute:
        queryset = queryset.filter(Item.another_attribute == another_attribute)
    ...
    (repeat above pattern for more attributes)
    ...
    if yet_another_attribute:
        queryset = queryset.filter(Item.yet_another_attribute == yet_another_attribute)
```

What is the preferred way of implementing the above behaviour? Are there any packages that will save me from having to do a lot of manual filtering that will give me the same behaviour as conveniently as the Django Rest Framework viewsets?

Or is manually including all the fields I want to filter on as optional query parameters, then checking for each parameter and then filtering if present the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but not yet perfect:

```
from fastapi.params import Depends

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_item(item: Item = Depends()):
    pass
```

See [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) for details.

The downside is that the parameters are required as maybe specified in the Item class.  It is possible to write a subclass with all optional parameters (e.g. like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67933226/2606766)).  It is working for instances of the class but FastAPI does not seem to reflect those in the API docs.  If anyone has a solution to that I'd be happy to learn.

Alternatively you can have multiple models as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61818217/2606766).  But I don't like this approach.

To answer your 2nd question you can access all generic parameters like this:

```
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_item(
    db: Session,
    id: Optional[int] = None,
    name: Optional[str] = None,
    another_attribute: Optional[str] = None,
    ...
    (more attributes)
    ...
    yet_another_attribute: Optional[str] = None
):
    params = locals().copy()
    ...
    for attr in [x for x in params if params[x] is not None]:
        query = query.filter(getattr(db_model.Item, attr).like(params[attr]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it's described in the docs.
Try this, ellipsis marking the field as required.

```
id: Optional[int] = Header(...)  # Header, path or any another place
```

See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/

Comment: thanks, so it looks like I'd still need to add the above line (`(attribute) = Optional(type) = Query(None)` for every attribute invidaually. Is there a way to automatically set a query parameter for each attribute of the model?

Comment: @AG Yes, use schemas as input input https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

Comment: The response model determines what gets returned, but I want to know if there is an easy way to filter on all attributes without manually adding it for each attribute

Comment: @AG Зlease read furtherю You can also use the same model (or another) as input: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model